# After migrating to Redux-Toolkit 2.0 and Redux 5.0 I am struggling in the extraReducer and createSlice a bit

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Here is my `formSlice` and I am getting "Expression expected" after the closing brackets of the `builder` and the arrow function.

```js
import { createAsyncThunk, createReducer, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

export const getform = createAsyncThunk("form/getForm", async () => {
  try {
    const result = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/autoroute/");
    return result.data;
  } catch (error) {}
});

export const addform = createAsyncThunk("form/add", async (form) => {
  try {
    const result = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/autoroute/", form);
    return result.data;
  } catch (error) {}
});

export const deleteform = createAsyncThunk("form/deleteForm", async (id) => {
  try {
    const result = await axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/autoroute/${id}`);
    return result.data;
  } catch (error) {}
});

export const updateform = createAsyncThunk(
  "form/deleteForm",
  async ({ id, form }) => {
    try {
      const result = await axios.put(
        `http://localhost:5000/autoroute/${id}`,
        form
      );
      return result.data;
    } catch (error) {}
  }
);

createReducer(initialState, builder = {
  form: [],
  status: null,
});

export const formSlice = createSlice({
  name: "form",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: builder =>{
    builder.getform(pending, (state) => {
      state.status = "pending";
    }),
    builder.getform(pending, (state) => {
      state.status = "success";
    }),
    builder.getform(pending, (state) => {
      state.status = "fail";
    }),
  },
});

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
// export const { increment, decrement, incrementByAmount } = counterSlice.actions;

export default formSlice.reducer;
```

It says "expression expected" after the closing bracket `builder` of the `extraReducers`. I was working on an older version of the Redux-Toolkit but the error showed me that I need to match my code with the newer version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is quite a bit of confusing non-valida JavaScript in your code, here are relevant parts corrected:

```js
// I don't know what you wanted to do with createReducer here but it seems you wanted to declare an initial state?
const initialState = {
  form: [],
  status: null,
};

export const formSlice = createSlice({
  name: "form",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: builder => {
    // instead of builder.getform(pending 
    builder.addCase(getform.pending, (state) => {
      state.status = "pending";
    }); // you can either do a semicolon here, or nothing, but not a comma
    // this is not an object definition, but a function body.
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The issue here is that you have managed to use Javascript's [Comma Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_operator) unintentionally.

> The comma (`,`) operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to
> right) and returns the value of the last operand. This is commonly
> used to provide multiple updaters to a [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop's afterthought.

In other words, the Javascript compiler/engine is expecting another expression after the last/trailing comma.

```js
export const formSlice = createSlice({
  name: "form",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: builder =>{
    builder.getform(pending, (state) => { // <-- expression
      state.status = "pending";
    }),
    builder.getform(pending, (state) => { // <-- expression
      state.status = "success";
    }),
    builder.getform(pending, (state) => { // <-- expression
      state.status = "fail";
    }),
    // <-- missing expected expression
  },
});
```

## Solution

The RTK slice's `extraReducers` property is a function and you should either be chaining from the `builder` object or explicitly defining each case.

The `builder` object has an `addCase` function that you should be using as well, `builder.getform` is not a function and would throw an error.

Expected use cases:

```js
export const formSlice = createSlice({
  name: "form",
  initialState,
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder
      .addCase(getform.pending, (state) => {
        state.status = "pending";
      })
      .addCase(getform.fulfilled, (state) => {
        state.status = "success";
      })
      .addCase(getform.rejected, (state) => {
        state.status = "fail";
      });
  },
});
```

or

```js
export const formSlice = createSlice({
  name: "form",
  initialState,
  extraReducers: builder =>{
    builder.addCase(getform.pending, (state) => {
      state.status = "pending";
    });
    builder.addCase(getform.fulfilled, (state) => {
      state.status = "success";
    });
    builder.addCase(getform.rejected, (state) => {
      state.status = "fail";
    });
  },
});
```